# Rename Schema Using Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

Assume that V1 of the Liquibase change set was defined like so:

```xml
<changeSet author="newco" id="create-old_table_name">  
    <createTable tableName="old_table_name">
        ...
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

V1 didn't define a schema name, therefore as I understand it has a default value, but in V2 I want to specify a schema name:

```xml
<changeSet author="newco" id="update-v2-rename-old_table_name">  
    <renameTable newTableName="old_table_name" 
                 oldTableName="old_table_name" 
                 schemaName="example"/>  
</changeSet>
```

But this doesn't work and throws an exception stating that the table name didn't change. Is it not possible to change the schema?

Comment: how would you like to change the schema and for which database? It's probably completelly different operation for each database.

Answer (score 0):

What DB change are you trying to achieve here?

If you want to move a table from one schema to another you will need to use a SQL change as the "[renameTable](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/rename-table.html)" change type is only for renaming a table within the same schema.

See e.g. [how to move tables from public to other schema in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770117/how-to-move-tables-from-public-to-other-schema-in-postgres) for the SQL needed to achieve that move in psql

Something like this?

```
<sql>
  ALTER TABLE old_table_name
  SET SCHEMA example;
</sql>
```